# Xcode App Creation Error : STATE_ERROR.APP_CREATE.PLATFORM_NOT_ALLOWED_DUE_TO_CONTRACT_STATE

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Just wanted to share the solution from a problem not yet addressed on Stack Overflow apparently.

From Xcode, when trying to distribute an iOS app on the App Store (via archive => distribute), I face this error:

> App record creation failed due to invalid input. Request failed with error code "STATE_ERROR.APP_CREATE.PLATFORM_NOT_ALLOWED_DUE_TO_CONTRACT_STATE", and reason "One or more platforms cannot be created for this app due to your provider's contract state. Creation of apps for the platform(s) iOS is not available due to your provider's contract state."

[image: A screenshot of the error returned by xcode]

Answer (score 22):

**WHAT DOES THAT MEAN**

It means you have some agreements / contract that you need to validate on app store connect.

**SOLUTION**

Connect to app store connect and agrees with last contractual elements set up by apple.
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/

Answer (score 0):

The above-mentioned issue occurs possibly because of 2 reasons.

1. You need to accept some of the agreements in your apple developer account (https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/agreements/)
2. You are using Enterprise Apple Developer Membership to submit application to App Store. Enterprise apple developer program won't allow users to submit application to AppStore or TestFlight it used different distribution mechanisms which you can find here (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/). You can check your account type under Membership Details in your Apple Developer Account[image]

I have faced the same problem because I am trying to submit application to App Store using Enterpise Apple Developer Account.